# Auto Complete in Razor MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my controller I was populating a select list like this

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getResponsibleInstitutions(String id)
    {
        Kitchen k = Kitchen.Get(id);
        return k.GetInstitutions().Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id,
            Text = c.Name
        });          
    }
```

Then using Viewbag I was populating a dropdown menu like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ingredients", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ingredients, "--Select Ingredients--")
```

But I want a text box instead of the select list which would have auto complete on it. What is the best approach to do it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: check this:http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopmentpassion.blogspot.com%2F2013%2F12%2Ffacebook-and-linkedin-like-searching.html&ei=KiuQVI7zO9bVaqaZgIgE&usg=AFQjCNFX88V1JeHG__FVOkyea12ek8rgjA&bvm=bv.81828268,d.d2s